# Regex: first capital letter between punctuation and a word

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to make a regular expression to find the beginning of a sentence that contains one of the words in a list. For example, if my string is:

"I at pie. He went shopping! She went to the gym last Thursday."

and my list of words is ["gym","Thursday"]

Searching the string for the regex should return "S".

Another example: searching the string "Tomorrow is Thursday. I will go to the gym." should return "T" (the first letter of "Tomorrow").

Lastly, if I have the string "Thursday is tomorrow.", I want it to return the "T" in Thursday.

What I have right now is:
`(?<=[.?!\|])(?:(?![.?!\|]).)*?(gym|Thursday)`
which matches " She went to the gym", " I will go to the gym", and nothing.

Comment: Try capturing it, `/([A-Za-z])[^.?!|]*?\b(?:gym|Thursday)\b[^.?!|]*/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `/(?:^|[.!] +)(?=[^.!]*\b(?:gym|Thursday)\b)(.)/`:

```js
const input = [
  'I at pie. He went shopping! She went to the gym last Thursday.',
  'Thursday is tomorrow.',
  'Tomorrow is Thursday. I will go to the gym.',
  'Tomorrow is Tuesday.'
];
const regex = /(?:^|[.!] +)(?=[^.!]*\b(?:gym|Thursday)\b)(.)/;
input.forEach((str) => {
  let m = str.match(regex);
  console.log(str + ' ==> ' + (m ? m[1] : null));
});
```

Output:

```
I at pie. He went shopping! She went to the gym last xThursday. ==> S
Thursday is tomorrow. ==> T
Tomorrow is Thursday. I will go to the gym. ==> T
Tomorrow is Tuesday. ==> null
```

Explanation:

- `(?:^|[.!] +)` - expect start of string, or end of sentence (add additional chars to character class as desired)
- `(?=[^.!]*\b(?:gym|Thursday)\b)` - positive lookahead for `gym` or `Thursday`, up the end of sentence, anchored by word boundaries
- `(.)` - capture the first character of the sentence

Answer (score 1):

```
/\b([A-Z])[^.?!\|]*?\b(gym|Thursday)/g
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/unEwXv/1)

The only trick here is using `[^.?!\|]` Which is 'any character except sentence terminators' to match a sentence